# Python String Replace Truncating New String

Tags: python, html, css, string

I have the following HTML document

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="firstScript.js"></script>
  <script src="secondScript.js"></script>
  ...
</head>
<body onload='function()' ..."></body>
</html>
```

This is great for development, but in the end I need to put all of those scripts and .css file directly into my html document rather than referencing them. To achieve this I wrote a little build script in python to replace each line containing a filename with the contents of that file wrapped in the appropriate html tags. Here's a little snippet to show what happens with javascript files.

```
FILES = [ "firstScript.js", "secondScript.js", ... ]
OUTPUT = "path/to/build.html"
for f in FILES:
  scriptFile = open(f, "r")
  scriptDAT = "<script>\n"+scriptFile.read()+"</script>"
  scriptFile.close()
  with fileinput.FileInput(OUTPUT, inplace=True) as file:
    for line in file:
      if line.find(f) >= 0: line = line.replace(line, scriptDAT)
      print(line)
```

This mostly works, but sometimes the line.replace will write everything in scriptDAT except for the `</script>` tag at the end. For example, if firstScript.js contains

```
function helloWorld() {
  console.log(helloWorld);
}
```

Then this script after replacing that first line might produce the html file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script>
  function helloWorld() {
    console.log("Hello World!");
  }
  <script src="secondScript.js"></script>
  ...
</head>
<body onload='function()' ..."></body>
</html>
```

The `line.replace(line, scripDAT)` ignoring the closing tag at the end of the string. The really strange thing is that this behaviour only happens sometimes; when the python script replaces secondScript.js it might include the closing tag. Does anyone know why the replace method is behaving this way?

Comment: I don't understand this bit: line.find(f) >= 0, what is your criteria to find the <script> tag?

Comment: I search the line for the filename `f`, if `line.find(f) >= 0` that means the line contains the reference to  the file `f`, and in that case I replace the entire line with `scriptDat` which includes the necessary `<script>` tags

Comment: Can it have something to do with the js file itself? I mean, do you have some .js for which the `replace` always works fine, and some for which it never works?

Comment: I'm not sure, I conjectured maybe it was that some of the js files were too long (some of them are thousands of lines), but one of my js files which has this error is only like 10. I suppose it could be an issue with the js file, but at this point I'm throwing darts blindfolded I have no idea what could be the cause of this issue.

Comment: It is not uncommon to have files that do not end in a newline.  If it were me, I'd add `...+"\n</script>"`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having your Javascript routines in separate files.  Browsers (obviously) handle that just fine, and it makes your HTML easier to read.

Comment: @TimRoberts we're using HTML a little unconventionally for this project. The end result requires everything to be compiled in one monstrous document so we can pass along one file and have it all self-contained.

But also you're suggestion of adding the escape character at the end tag nearly solved it. If you add one at the end too `...+"\n</script>\n"` then the issue somehow disappears...